# Selenium Webdriver - Input js/html elements identification

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, element, identification

Have problem with identification of input elements.

For instance have two fields like this ...

```
<div class="col-xs-10">
  <h4>
    <a href="#" data-type="text" id="firstName" class="editable editable-click">
      Alejandroff
    </a>
  </h4>
  <h4>
    <a href="#" data-type="text" id="lastName" class="editable editable-click">
      Puchauff
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

... which after click on eg. Name is changed to this ...

```
<div class="col-xs-10">
  <h4>
    <a href="#" data-type="text" id="firstName" class="editable editable-click editable-open" style="display: none;">
      Alejandroff
    </a>
    <span class="editable-container editable-inline" style="">
      <div>
        <div class="editableform-loading" style="display: none;">
        </div>
        <form class="form-inline editableform" style="">
          <div class="control-group">
            <div>
              <div class="editable-input" style="position: relative;">
                <input type="text" class="input-medium" style="padding-right: 24px;">
                <span class="editable-clear-x">
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="editable-error-block help-block" style="display: none;">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </span>
  </h4>
  <h4>
    <a href="#" data-type="text" id="lastName" class="editable editable-click" style="display: inline;">
      Puchauff
    </a>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Till now identified Name input element like

```
xpath = "//*[@id="userDetails"]/div[1]/div[1]/h4[1]/span/div/form/div/div[1]/div/input
```

but I know it's incorrect cause it makes my test fragile (in case when dev will eg. remove one div test will fail).

Could anyone advice how to identify input in another way ?

Comment: I don't see the element with id = userDetails in the HTML you provided. Will you please add that? It may help identify a better way to find the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
"//a[@id='firstName']//following::input[@class='input-medium']"
```

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see `userDetails` defined on the markdown you provided, but you need something unique to rely on. So given that you want this input:

```
                        <div class="editable-input" style="position: relative;">
                            <input type="text" class="input-medium" style="padding-right: 24px;">
                                <span class="editable-clear-x"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

you could use the `id="firstName"` identificator. So try something like

```
//div[@id="firstName"]//..//input[@class="input-medium"]
```

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element   :(